# Why am I getting these errors while importing necessary code for the google sheets api

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-sheets-api

I am running windows 10 and using the intellij IDE and have loaded credentials.json into the resources section already. I have been following several tutorials on how to set this stuff up including googles own java quickstart explanation.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
```

When using what has been described to me as the necessary imports to use the google sheets api I get the following error. " Cannot resolve symbol 'google' " My assumption is that I have done something wrong in the process of setting up gradle or that I am simply failing due to my probable lack of competence.

Comment: When/where does it say that?

Comment: @esqew That post seems to have fixed my issue thank you so much! That issue was holding me back from completing a major part for my senior project.